# Place Order button not working Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and currently have a problem with the " Place Order " button , not working. The problem only occurs when I logged into my account but if I make a purchase as a guest sends me to the success page. I have been researching the problem and do not send me answer this because I made a module that sends me the following message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getStreet() on a non-object in cellairis/app/code/local/Cellairis/Ciudades/Model/Observer.php on line 28
```

That is my Observer.php. It looks fine and i really don't know where is the issue.

```
   <?php
class Cellairis_Ciudades_Model_Observer {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function editAccount(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        try {
            $result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer') -> getCollection() -> getLastItem();
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer') -> load($result -> getId());

            // API METHOD
            $method = 'client';

            // GET THE EMAIL PARAM
            $email = $customer -> getEmail();

            // PARAMETER TO API
            $data = array('email' => $email);

            // CALL HELPER TO CONNECT WITH API
            $response = Mage::helper('ciudades/connection') -> connectApi($method, 'POST', $data);
            if (empty($response -> client)) {
                try {
                    $cliente = 'M' . $result -> getId();
                    $nombre = $customer -> getFirstname() . ' ' . $customer -> getLastname();
                    $direccion = $customer -> getDefaultBillingAddress() -> getStreet(1);
                    $delegacion = $customer -> getDefaultBillingAddress() -> getCity();
                    $colonia = $customer-> getDefaultBillingAddress() -> getStreet(2);
                    $estado = $customer -> getDefaultBillingAddress() -> getRegion();
                    $pais = $customer -> getDefaultBillingAddress() -> getCountry();
                    $cp = $customer -> getDefaultBillingAddress() -> getPostcode();
                    $rfc = $customer -> getDefaultBillingAddress() -> getVatId();
                    $telefono = $customer -> getDefaultBillingAddress() -> getTelephone();

                    // IF RESPONSE DOESN'T EXISTS CONNECT WITH WS TO CREATE CUSTOMER IN CELLAIRIS ERP
                    // API METHOD
                    $method = 'createCustomer';

                    // CREATE ARRAY TO SEND TO WS
                    $data = array(
                        'Cliente' => $cliente,
                        'Nombre' => $nombre,
                        'Direccion' => $direccion,
                        'Delegacion' => $delegacion,
                        'Colonia' => $colonia,
                        'Estado' => $estado,
                        'Pais' => $pais,
                        'CodigoPostal' => $cp,
                        'RFC' => $rfc,
                        'Telefonos' => $telefono,
                        'Email' => $email,
                        'Descripcion1' => 'Ecommerce'
                    );

                    // CALL HELPER TO CONNECT WITH API
                    $createCustomer = Mage::helper('ciudades/connection') -> connectApi($method, 'POST', $data);
                    $customer -> setNoCliente($cliente);
                    $customer -> save();
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    Mage::log(Mage::app() -> getRequest() -> getRouteName() . "/" . Mage::app() -> getRequest() -> getControllerName() . "/" . Mage::app() -> getRequest() -> getActionName() . " -> Ocurrio un error con el Cliente " . $email . ". ERROR=" . $ex -> getMessage(), Zend_Log::ERR);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {

            Mage::log(Mage::app() -> getRequest() -> getRouteName() . "." . Mage::app() -> getRequest() -> getControllerName() . "." . Mage::app() -> getRequest() -> getActionName() . " > " . $e -> getMessage(), Zend_Log::ERR);

        }
    }}
```

I appreciate your quickly help. Thanks.

Comment: please fix the code formating

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the address directly from the customer/address model. I have edited your code

I have also indented and formatted your code.

```
<?php

public function editAccount(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    try {

        $result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->getLastItem();
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($result->getId());

        $customerBillingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
        $customerBillingAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerBillingAddressId); //address as object

        // API METHOD
        $method = 'client';

        // GET THE EMAIL PARAM
        $email = $customer->getEmail();

        // PARAMETER TO API
        $data = array('email' => $email);

        // CALL HELPER TO CONNECT WITH API
        $response = Mage::helper('ciudades/connection')->connectApi($method, 'POST', $data);
        if (empty($response->client)) {
            try {

                $cliente = 'M' . $result->getId();
                $nombre = $customer->getFirstname() . ' ' . $customer->getLastname();
                $direccion = $customerBillingAddress->getStreet(1);
                $delegacion = $customerBillingAdress->getCity();
                $colonia = $customerBillingAddress->getStreet(2);
                $estado = $customerBillingAddress->getRegion();
                $pais = $customerBillingAddress->getCountry();
                $cp = $customerBillingAddress->getPostcode();
                $rfc = $customerBillingAddress->getVatId();
                $telefono = $customerBillingAddress->getTelephone();

                // IF RESPONSE DOESN'T EXISTS CONNECT WITH WS TO CREATE CUSTOMER IN CELLAIRIS ERP
                // API METHOD
                $method = 'createCustomer';

                // CREATE ARRAY TO SEND TO WS
                $data = array(
                    'Cliente' => $cliente,
                    'Nombre' => $nombre,
                    'Direccion' => $direccion,
                    'Delegacion' => $delegacion,
                    'Colonia' => $colonia,
                    'Estado' => $estado,
                    'Pais' => $pais,
                    'CodigoPostal' => $cp,
                    'RFC' => $rfc,
                    'Telefonos' => $telefono,
                    'Email' => $email,
                    'Descripcion1' => 'Ecommerce'
                );

                // CALL HELPER TO CONNECT WITH API
                $createCustomer = Mage::helper('ciudades/connection')->connectApi($method, 'POST', $data);
                $customer->setNoCliente($cliente);
                $customer->save();

            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                Mage::log(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName() . "/" . Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() . "/" . Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName() . " -> Ocurrio un error con el Cliente " . $email . ". ERROR=" . $ex->getMessage(),
                    Zend_Log::ERR);
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        Mage::log(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName() . "." . Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() . "." . Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName() . " > " . $e->getMessage(),
            Zend_Log::ERR);

    }
}
```

Comment: `getStreet(1)` is actually valid: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php#L106

Answer (score -1):

This line seems to be the problem:

```
$customer -> getDefaultBillingAddress() -> getStreet(1)
```

Some customers do not have a default billing address. For example new customers that have not ordered anything yet or customers who deleted all their addresses in their account.

I guess your observer is not called for guest orders, because it will break every time, independent of who is logged in. I don't know what the code is supposed to du but this is probably not what you want:

```
    $result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer') -> getCollection() -> getLastItem();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer') -> load($result -> getId());
```

It loads **all customers in memory** (that means, it will crash your server with a big customer database), then loads the last one again. While "last" will most likely be the latest registered, it does not guarantee a particular order because no order was specified in the collection.

Comment: `getCollection()->getLastItem()` doesn't load all customers in memory?

Comment: It does: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php#L285-L289

Comment: What you want to do instead is `setOrder()`  and `setPageSize(1)`

Comment: apologies, you are correct. This also answers "Why is magento so slow?!"